# Pg-promise: chaining conditional queries

Tags: javascript, express, bluebird, pg-promise

I'm trying to find the correct way of chaining conditional queries.

Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate my situation:

```
check whether the an item exists;
  if no:
    reply with status 404;
  if yes:
    check whether the user owns the item;
      if no:
        redirect to another page;
      if yes:
        retrieve the information about the item and render the page;
```

My first intuition would be to use [tasks](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#task) in order to reuse the same connection but because of the different possible outcomes, I am having a hard time figuring out how to properly deal with the promises:

```
db.task(t => {
  return t.items.exists(itemId)
    .then(exists => {
      if (!exists) { // item does not exist
        // 404
      }

      return t.items.isOwner(itemId, userId)
        .then(isOwner => {
          if (!isOwner) {
            // redirect to some other page
          }

          return t.items.getById(itemId);
        })
    })
})
.then(data => {
  // OK, process data and render
})
.catch(console.error); // unexpected errors
```

If I try to redirect to a 404 page for instance, the promise will still be resolved afterwards.
An another way would be to have the following:

```
if (!exists) { // item does not exist
  return Promise.reject('404');
}

...

.then(data => {
  // OK, process data and render
}, reason => {
  // KO, conditions were not met to resolve
})
```

which 'works', but catches both errors and unmet conditions. I would prefer to have a dedicated 'unmet condition' handler.

Yet another approach I thought of:

```
var p = db.task(t => {
  return t.items.exists(itemId)
    .then(exists => {
      if (!exists) { // item does not exist
        //  resolve p (and break promise chain) with something like
        //  p.resolve(() => {
        //    return res.redirect...
        //  });
      }

      // else we can go on with the queries
      return t.items.isOwner(itemId, userId);
    }
    .then(isOwner => {
      if (!isOwner) {
        // resolve p and redirect to some other page
      }

      return t.items.getById(itemId);
    })
    .then(item => {
      // everything OK, resolve with a handler to render the page
    });
})
.then(action => {
  action();
})
.catch(console.error); // unexpected errors
```

But I don't see any way I can resolve `p`. Calling `Promise.resolve(...)` inside a nested promise resolves the next promise itself before falling through `p`'s `then`.

What is the recommended way of chaining conditional queries and dealing with different results in `pg-promise` while keeping an eye on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that the author has is mainly with using promises, and not so much with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

```
db.task('easy-peasy', async t => {
    if (await t.items.exists(itemId)) {
        // reply with status 404;
    } else {
        if (await t.items.isOwner(itemId, userId)) {
            // redirect to some other page
        } else {
            return t.items.getById(itemId); // return the data
        }
    }
})
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            // Task returned data;
            // Render the data;
        }
    })
    .catch(console.error); // unexpected errors
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you.

This would still require the item to fall through each of the promises until it reaches either the last `then` block or the `catch` block.

```
// First Condition
const input = 'test input'
Promise.resolve({ item: input })



  // Repeat this for different condition on `item.item` and change `X`
  /* REPEAT START */
  .then(data => {
    if (data.hitCondition != null && data.hitCondition !== '') {
      return data;
    }

    if (conditionX(data)) {
      return Object.assign({}, data, { 
        hitCondition: 'conditionX'
      });
    }

    return data;
  })
  /* REPEAT END */




  ...



  .then(result => {
    const { item, hitCondition } = result
    if (hitCondition != null && hitCondition !== '') {
      // at least one condition is met
      // check hitCondition to see which condition is hit
    } else {
      // none of the conditions are met
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Some error happened somewhere
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: It works fine in my scenario, thanks. I wonder if the falling-through has any performance impact with more promises and under heavy load. I'd still prefer a less hacky way but in the meantime I'll gladly take your approach ;)